# Add onClick event on a preview image in DropzoneArea (Material-ui)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this DropzoneArea component from Material ui and I'm trying to add an onClick event on the file so that I can open a modal with the full size image from the preview image url.

```
<DropzoneArea
  acceptedFiles={['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/bmp']}
  clearOnUnmount
  dropzoneClass={classes.imageArea}
  dropzoneText="Imagem"
  filesLimit={1}
  getFileAddedMessage={(fileName) => {
    return `Arquivo ${fileName} anexado.`;
  }}
  getDropRejectMessage={(rejectedFile) => {
    return `Este formato de arquivo ${rejectedFile.type} não é permitido.`;
  }}
  getFileRemovedMessage={(fileName) => {
    return `Arquivo ${fileName} removido.`;
  }}
  id="drop"
  initialFiles={[storageUrl + factura.Ficheiro]}
  maxFileSize={5000000}
  onChange={(files) => handleFileUpload(files)}
  showPreviewsInDropzone={true}
  previewGridProps={{
    container: {
      spacing: 1,
      direction: 'row',
      justify: 'center'
    }
  }}
/>;
```

[the result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6OSf.png)

I can't find a way to do it. I've been looking over and over the mui props for this component. Does anyone knows any prop that could help me out on that?